# Error handling in async.parallel

Tags: node.js

I have a function which uses async.parallel function to call two functions. But I don't know how to handle errors when async.parallel is used. If one of the two functions throw errors, how do I handle them?

```
exports.getProductconfigWithProductList = function(req, res){

var apiVersion = req.param('version', null);
var product_id = req.params.productId;
dbDriver = determineDriver('es');

async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            dbDriver.getProductconfig(product_id,function(data){
                callback(null, data);
            });
        },
        function(callback) {
            var productListPromise = getProductListData();
            productListPromise.then(function(data) {
                callback(null, data);
            });
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        if(!err){
            var data = results[0];
            data[1] = results[1];
            res.send(data);
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'+err+'>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
            res.send(err);
            res.end();
        }

    }
);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have:

```
async.parallel([
    func1,
    func2,
], (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        // you handle the errors here
    }
});
```

It's explained in more detail in the docs:

- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

and in the issue on GitHub here:

- https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/334

Comment: so what about the callbacks I defined in each function? Can I only call callback(data) without null and still I can catch errors inside that if(err)?

Comment: I want to know how to implement error handling. Not the theory part. I have no idea how to handle those errors. If I remove 'null' from my callbacks, it doesn't execute properly.